# How can I edit the values of coordinates within a geojson file?

Tags: dictionary, geojson, geopandas, folium, utm

I am trying to map a geojson file (A map of Alaska precincts, downloaded from the division of elections and then converted online to geojson) onto a choropleth map using folium, the problem is the coordinates are in 7-digit numbers like this:

[ -16624764.227, 8465801.1497 ]

I read on a similar post that this was most likely a US coordinate system like UTM or State Plane, and recommended using an API to reproject it. Is it also possible to access the coordinates directly such as with geopandas and divide them by 100000?

Answer (score 0):

The data is most likely in a specific [cartographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection). You don't just want to divide by 100k - the data will likely have nonlinear transformations which have a different effect on the position depending on the location. See the GeoPandas docs on [working with projections](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/projections.html).

If the CRS of the data is correctly encoded, you can re-project the dataframe into lat/lons (e.g. WGS84, which has the EPSG Code 4326) using [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html), e.g.:

```py
df_latlon = df.to_crs("epsg:4326")
```

Comment: Tank you so much! When I try that I get the following error:
RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'

I've read this is due to a lack of dependencies. Do I need to install proj?

The geojson comes with the following crs:
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } }

Comment: I'm not sure about that error, but yeah you do need proj and PyProj installed in order for this to work. see the [geopandas dependencies](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#dependencies) for more info